# Return list built from a loop with lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function to return a list of files and folders in a given folder (with recurse and only get files options), or just the file in a list if given path is not a folder:

```
def path_to_list(path, onlyFiles = False, recurse = False):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        if onlyFiles:
            if recurse:
                result = []
                for dirs in list(os.walk(path)):
                    result.append(dirs[2])
                return result
            else:
                return next(os.walk(path))[2]
    else:
        return list(os.walk(path)) if recurse else next(os.walk(path))

    return [path]
```

Trying to shorten this part:

```
result = []
for dirs in list(os.walk(path)):
    result.append(dirs[2])
return result
```

I tried to use lambda with multiple syntaxes but haven't got any success. How do I directly return the result from the for loop? Thanks.

Comment: `result = [dirs[2] for dirs in list(os.walk(path))]` or simply `return [dirs[2] for dirs in list(os.walk(path))]`. You seem to know how to code, so take a look at list comprehensions

Comment: what happens if `onlyFiles = False` which is the default value? It does not seem that this is handled correctly

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Seems OK. I tried `return [dirs[2] for dirs in list(os.walk(path))]` without brackets before which didn't work. Here's the result with `onlyFiles ` and `recurse`: [['01.opus', '02.opus', '03.opus', '04.opus', '05.opus'], ['1.opus']]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return list of directories by:

```
return [dir for _, _, dir in list(os.walk(path))]
```